# consulta con uso de Case en Mysql?

Tags: mysql

```
    select 
      case when precio<2000 then
        (select concat_ws(" ","Tarjetas madres menores a 2000 pesos",  
        (select * from componente inner join tarjetaMadre on
        componente.id_componente=tarjetaMadre.id_componente)) else 
      case when precio<5000 then 
        (select concat_ws(" ","Tarjetas madres menores a 5000 pesos",  
        (select * from componente inner join tarjetaMadre on
        componente.id_componente=tarjetaMadre.id_componente))) else 
      case when precio>5000
        (select concat_ws(" ","Tarjetas madres mayores a 5000 pesos",  
        (select * from componente inner join tarjetaMadre on
        componente.id_componente=tarjetaMadre.id_componente))) end 
    from componente, tarjetaMadre where
    componente.id_componente=tarjetaMadre.id_componente;
```

**mysql tengo ese case pero me marca un error y no logro descifrarlo**

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near:

```
'else case when precio<5000 then (select concat_ws(" ","Tarjetas madres menores' at line 3 mysql>
```

Comment: podrías hacer un `select *` de tus dos tablas (al menos algunas filas) y pegarlo en tu pregunta?

Answer (score 2):

No puedes usar una tupla como argumento de `concat_ws`. Sólo funcionaría si en cada subconsulta eliges sólo un campo. Por otro lado, pareciera que intentas hacer una agrupación por rango de precio, pero es muy ineficiente que hagas la misma subconsulta en cada condición.

Finalmente, la sintaxis de `CASE` es

```
CASE
WHEN condicion1 THEN x
WHEN condicion2 THEN y
[ELSE z]
END
```

Si quieres hacer CASE anidados, cada uno debe tener su END

```
case
when precio<5000 then 'precio menor a 5000'
else case
     when precio<10000 then 'precio menor a 10000'
     else 
         case 
         when precio> 1000 then 'precio mayor a 10000' 
         end
     end
end as rango_precio
```

(pero sigue siendo ineficiente usar CASE anidados en este caso)

Dependiendo de lo que quieres hacer, probablemente debas hacer una subconsulta que contenga:

```
select *,
case
when precio<5000 then 'precio menor a 5000'
when precio<10000 then 'precio menor a 10000'
else 'precio mayor a 10000'
end as rango_precio
from 
componente join tarjetamadre using (id_componente)
```

[Fiddle de ejemplo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/db102b/7)

Y a partir de su resultado hacer la agrupación que corresponda.

Comment: no entendí. La consulta principal necesita el join porque supongo que una tabla contiene los precios y la otra los modelos (por ejemplo)

Comment: hablo de los beneficios que tiene tu respuesta, solo haces un join los demas por cada case un join

Comment: Ah, claro. En general meter subconsultas como parte de los campos del SELECT es muy, muy ineficiente.

Answer (score 0):

Te falta un parentesis.

Corregido:

```
    select 
  case when precio<2000 then
    (select concat_ws(" ","Tarjetas madres menores a 2000 pesos",  
    (select * from componente inner join tarjetaMadre on
    componente.id_componente=tarjetaMadre.id_componente))) else 
  case when precio<5000 then 
    (select concat_ws(" ","Tarjetas madres menores a 5000 pesos",  
    (select * from componente inner join tarjetaMadre on
    componente.id_componente=tarjetaMadre.id_componente))) else 
  case when precio>5000
    (select concat_ws(" ","Tarjetas madres mayores a 5000 pesos",  
    (select * from componente inner join tarjetaMadre on
    componente.id_componente=tarjetaMadre.id_componente))) end 
from componente, tarjetaMadre where
componente.id_componente=tarjetaMadre.id_componente;
```